# Friedrichs extension of the Laplacian from a smooth subspace and density of its eigenbasis in the Frechet topology of the subspace as well?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Let $C^\infty_\text{div}(\mathbb{T}^3)$ be the "real" Frechet space of periodic, divergence-free smooth vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^3$. That is, $\mathbb{T}^3$ is the $3$-dimensional torus.

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be the "complex" Hilbert space completion of $C^\infty_\text{div}(\mathbb{T}^3)$ in the $L^2$ space $L^2(\mathbb{T}^3, \mathbb{C}^3)$.

Then, I read from standard literatures that a Friedrichs extension of the Laplacian $-\Delta : C^\infty_\text{div}(\mathbb{T}^3) \to C^\infty_\text{div}(\mathbb{T}^3)$ yields the extension of $-\Delta$ as an unbounded self-adjiont operator on $\mathcal{H}$. Moreover there exists a countable subset $\{f_n\} \subset C^\infty_\text{div}(\mathbb{T}^3)$ which is an orthonormal basis for this extended Laplacian in $\mathcal{H}$.

Now, my question is that:

1. Is this $\{f_n \}$ also dense in  $C^\infty_{div}(\mathbb{T}^3)$ with respect to its own"Frechet topology"?
2. Is it possible to choose, say, $f_1$ as a constant vector? For example, I would like to choose $f_1=(1,0,0)$

The above questions do not seem to be answered clearly in any text I searched for. Could anyone pleas clarify?